# Mysql simulating FULL OUTER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, union, outer-join, join

I have 2 tables users and orders, I want get users and his orders count

```
SELECT `users`.*, `orders`.*,count(*) FROM `users` LEFT JOIN orders ON  
`users`.`id` = `orders`.`user_id` 
UNION SELECT `users`.*, `orders`.*,count(*) FROM users 
RIGHT JOIN orders ON `users`.`id` = `orders`.`user_id`
```

This query select users and order count of users which have order, but not select users who not have orders .

What I want get

```
user orders
John   5
Thomas 0
Mike   8
```

What I  get

```
user orders
John   5
Mike   8
```

How to get also users who not have orders ?

Comment: If you want just `User` and `Order` columns why are doing a `SELECT *`?

Comment: @Declan_K ok but it's not there problem I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query will give you a list of all users and the count of their orders, including 0 if that user has no orders.

Also, are you sure that ORDER_ID is the FK to the user table? That seems counter-intuative to me...

```
SELECT U.NAME
        ,COUNT(O.ORDER_ID)
FROM    USERS U
LEFT OUTER JOIN
        ORDERS O
ON      U.ID = O.ORDER_ID
GROUP BY
        U.NAME
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a full outer join for this.  A left outer join should be fine, assuming that all the users in the `orders` table have a valid reference to the `users` table:

```
SELECT u.*, count(o.user_id)
FROM `users` u LEFT JOIN
      orders o
      ON u.`id` = o.`user_id` 
group by u.id
```